# Using Object.assign on an object within an object

Tags: javascript, object

How do I use Object.assign to update the second object in the allMsgs array?

I have:

```
let v = {
  allMsgs: [
    {
        a: 111,
        b: [],
    },

    {
        a: 222,
        b: [],
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to have a copy of v so that it is:

```
let v = {
  allMsgs: [
    {
        a: 111,
        b: [],
    },

    {
        a: 222,
        b: ['newItem],
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I use Object.assign for this?

Comment: why `Object.assing`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the part which you want to update

```js
let v = {
  allMsgs: [
    {
        a: 111,
        b: [],
    },

    {
        a: 222,
        b: [],
    }
  ]
};
 let vCopy = { allMsgs: v.allMsgs.map(msg => Object.assign({}, msg))};
vCopy.allMsgs[1] = Object.assign(vCopy.allMsgs[1], { b: ['newItem'] });

console.log('copy', vCopy);
console.log('actual', v);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is not to mutate the original object, then you would do it like this:

```js
let v = {
  allMsgs: [
    { a: 111, b: [] }, 
    { a: 222, b: [] }
  ]
};

let w = { allMsgs: Object.assign([...v.allMsgs], 
           { 1: Object.assign({}, v.allMsgs[1], 
               {b: ['newItem']} 
           )}
        )};

console.log('updated =', w);
console.log('original =', v);
```

Note that here the first object in `allMsgs` is still shared between the two objects. Only the one you wanted to change is (obviously) separate.

Libraries like immutable.js have nice methods for making such updates using a concise syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Without [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), you could address the array directly and push the value.

```js
var v = { allMsgs: [{ a: 111, b: [] }, { a: 222, b: [] }] };

v.allMsgs[1].b.push('newItem');

console.log(v);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```